# How to remove requirement to enter password for Access mdb

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access 97 format file - that I am opening Using Access 2010.
I have the access password, but would like to remove the requirement to enter a password on opening the file.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: interesting option...

Comment: perfect, thanks - if you enter as an answer, i will check it off as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my situation. I use a shortcut with a target similar to:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\databases\PDCFE.mdb" /user user_name /wrkgrp "F:\PDC\sec.mdw" /pwd ""
```